# Convert numerical variable to categorical variable

Tags: r

I have a list of columns that contain 0 and 1 as values. Right now they are treated as numerical variables but I want them to be treated as categorical.

I tried

```
as.factor(df[,"diseasesA":"diseaseM"], exclude = NULL)
```

but received the following error message:

```r
Error in as.factor(df[,"diseasesA":"diseaseM"],  : 
  unused argument (exclude = NULL)
```

not using `"exclude = NULL"` gave me the following error message:

```r
Error in "diseasesA":"diseaseM" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(jsub, setattr(as.list(seq_along(x)), "names", names_x),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In eval(jsub, setattr(as.list(seq_along(x)), "names", names_x),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Are you coming to R from Python? Indexing columns in R doesn't work that way (`string:string`). We can't see any of your data, so it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`factor()` or `as.factor()` works on a single column, not a data frame. So you need to apply that function to the columns you want to convert. Here are a few equivalent methods:

```
cols = paste0("disease", LETTERS[1:13]) # assuming your naming pattern is consistent

## base R with lapply
df[cols] = lapply(df[cols], factor)

## base R with for loop
for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
  df[[i]] = factor(df[[i]])
}

## dplyr
library(dplyr)
df = df %>%
  mutate(across(diseaseA:diseaseM, factor))
```

I will note that your question is inconsistent in its column naming pattern, `disease` vs `diseases`. In the base R methods I assumed that's a typo and further assumed you wanted to convert columns `diseaseA`, `diseaseB`, `diseaseC`, ..., `diseaseM`. In `dplyr` we can use `across()` to use `X:Z` to operate on all columns starting with `X` through `Z`--but there are many other methods possible to select which columns to work on, e.g., `starts_with("diesease")`.